# How to embed swf file in floating iframe on website via. bookmarklet?

Tags: html, flash, iframe

I am a high schooler & a novice to bookmarklets. I want a bookmarklet that can make a floating iframe on top of a website with a .swf file as it's contents. I've tried many solutions, but a major obstacle is that simply pasting the .swf link as an iframe content ("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/shirtjs/gstore@v1/cubefield_24.swf". I know, it's stupid.) just downloads the swf file, as we are using moderated chromebooks. Can somebody provide me a bookmarklet code that makes this?

Answer (score 0):

> *"...But a major obstacle is that simply pasting the `.swf` URL link as an `iframe` content just downloads the swf file, as we are using moderated chromebooks."*

This has nothing to do with moderators. As a software security issue, Chrome **does not** accept/load direct links to SWF files unless the link is inside a media tag like `<object>` or `<embed>`.

(maybe) **solution:**

Consider your current `<iframe>` line...

```
<iframe src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/shirtjs/gstore@v1/cubefield_24.swf"></iframe>
```

Replace with `<embed>`code...

```
<embed src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/shirtjs/gstore@v1/cubefield_24.swf" width="550" height="400">
```